# Module 'cairo' has no 'Context' member

Tags: python, cairo

When I am trying to run [this example](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/blob/master/examples/pycairo_examples.ipynb), I am getting the following problem messages:

1. Module 'cairo' has no 'ImageSurface' member
2. Module 'cairo' has no 'Context' member
3. Module 'cairo' has no 'FORMAT_ARGB32' member

What is the problem here?

Comment: The example will not load please share you code

Comment: https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/blob/master/examples/pycairo_examples.ipynb This is the link to the code

Comment: Same issue as this and I cannot decide which one to close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64886845/module-cairo-has-no-imagesurface-member

Comment: I've got the same, seems to be some problem in the cairo library making it unable to lint properly

Comment: @vidstige I tried running the code by installing cairo using Anaconda and it worked out (earlier I was running the code by installing cairo using pip). You can check if it also works for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Pycairo](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo) requires cairo C header files to be installed on your system. It's written in the ["Getting Started"](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) section of the documentation.

The reason why the example worked with Anaconda is because Anaconda installed cairo as a **conda package**.

A conda package is built using a conda recipe (e.g. [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/cairo-feedstock) is the one for cairo) by a tool called conda-build. When the cairo conda package is being built, conda-build follows what it's written in the [meta.yaml](https://github.com/conda-forge/cairo-feedstock/blob/24af3bed13afbb7833442f79ac387fbf65e9ac5e/recipe/meta.yaml) file of the conda recipe. As you can see from `meta.yml` file, cairo is downloaded as a tarball. Then if you are on Windows, conda-build runs the [bld.bat](https://github.com/conda-forge/cairo-feedstock/blob/a83da3d9f33117cb8c797f48a7af350fd569721e/recipe/bld.bat) file and compiles cairo. Otherwise, if you are on Linux or macOS, conda-build does the same thing using the [build.sh](https://github.com/conda-forge/cairo-feedstock/blob/a83da3d9f33117cb8c797f48a7af350fd569721e/recipe/build.sh) file. In other words, Anaconda (via conda-build) installed the cairo C header files for you.

*Note*: I'm not a conda expert, and I think oversimplified the process how conda-build works. If you are interested, here is a link to the [official conda-build documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/concepts/recipe.html).