# Module 'cairo' has no 'ImageSurface' member

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

When I am trying to execute [this example](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#example), I am getting problem messages like:

1. Module 'cairo' has no 'FORMAT_ARGB32' member
2. Module 'cairo' has no 'ImageSurface' member
3. Module 'cairo' has no 'Context' member
4. Module 'cairo' has no 'LinearGradient' member

What is the problem here?

I am using python version '3.9.0' and pycairo version '1.20.0'

Comment: Same issue and I cannot decide which one to close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880743/module-cairo-has-no-context-member

Comment: Do you have the solution? I am new to cairo and unable to proceed my learning due to this issue. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, nope, I do not. I do not have much clue about pycairo. I would guess that you have a file `cairo.py` laying around somewhere and are not loading the real pycairo, but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you named your file `cairo.py` ?